# Memcpy crash only on iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, ios7, 64-bit

All,

I am facing a strange issue with iPhone 5s. I am doing a `HMAC-SHA1` encrypting in my app using a third party library. The library uses `memcpy`, which am not aware what it is, as I am not into too much of memory level programming in `C`. The encryption works perfectly fine in all iphones except the `64 bit 5s`. Below is the code where it crashes `(5th line)`.

```
void SHA1Update(SHA1_CTX* context, unsigned char* data, unsigned int len)
{
unsigned int i, j;

    j = (context->count[0] >> 3) & 63;
    if ((context->count[0] += len << 3) < (len << 3)) context->count[1]++;
    context->count[1] += (len >> 29);
    if ((j + len) > 63) {
        memcpy(&context->buffer[j], data, (i = 64-j));
        SHA1Transform(context->state, context->buffer);
        for ( ; i + 63 < len; i += 64) {
            SHA1Transform(context->state, &data[i]);
        }
        j = 0;
    }
    else i = 0;
    memcpy(&context->buffer[j], &data[i], len - i);
}
```

Below is the crash details

> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>   Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x001a9c799cbfdcf9
>   Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:
>   0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000191c34dc8 _platform_memmove + 40
>   1   Anyvan                          0x00000001001fc6a8 SHA1Update (sha1.c:128)
>   2   Anyvan                          0x00000001000c7efc hmac_sha1 (hmac.c:73)
>   3   Anyvan                          0x00000001000fe7cc -[LoginViewController callAuth:] (LoginViewController.m:360)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Crashes only on 5c? How about 5s, 5, 4s, 4...etc?

Comment: Crashes only on 5S. Other are good. Am suspecting 64 bit version of the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is crashing because you are using `int` not because of `memcpy`. Try replacing the `int` with `NSInteger` and it should work. You can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

The iPhone5S uses a 64bit architecture while the others use 32bit. One of the core differences between the two is how the system handles integers as explained in the doc. Your code is using `unsigned int` which does not mean the same thing on 32bit and on 64bit and that results in a crash. You should change your `int` called `i` and `j` to `NSIntegers` and I believe your code will work. Or come to think of it you can try to simply replace the word `int` by `long`.

Comment: Your link does not work, says _"Sorry, that page cannot be found."_

Comment: Sorry. I changed it. Try again.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more. Which variable do you want me to change?

Comment: I understand that now. But unfortunately thats a C file that we are talking about. I failed to mention that. Its in Sha1.c file that I got from OAuthConsumer library.

Comment: did you try changing `int` to `long`?

Comment: Mikael... Thanks for the suggestion. Definitely the issue should be around it. But now I moved into CCHMAC already provided by iOS instead of using the c library. thanks all

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem when compiling a Twitter+OAuth library for 64 bit platforms. I resolved it by replacing "unsigned long" by "uint32_t" in 7 places in sha1.h and sha1.c. Like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef struct {
    uint32_t state[5];
    uint32_t count[2];
    unsigned char buffer[64];
} SHA1_CTX;
```

You also need to include the stdint.h library (at the top of sha1.h and maybe sha1.c) to make this work. uint32_t is always 32 bits and I think that SHA1's transformation macros like R0 fail when operating on 64 bit data types. So changing to an explicit 32 bit data type fixes it. The answer about memcpy led me to this solution.

Answer (score -1):

Remove support for arm64 if its not that important. Then set NO for "Build Active Architecture Only" (debug and release)

That did the trick for me, I didn't really need any 64bit specific functionality on my app so I took it out.

Comment: But thats just a hack. You cant evade away from 64 bit for ever. Thats the future

Comment: Being almost 2020, I can confirm what @Kesava said.

Answer (score -1):

void CSHA1::Update(UINT_8 *data, long len){}

i just changed len form UINT_32 to long, and it did work, now can run on 4s, 5,5s,6 hah