# App crashes on some device with Application exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm working on an iOS app and it load images from an URL [like this image](http://api.ba-cha.me/data/1400300898-bf7451bb6d31da50ed76f61462efecc5.jpg) it is working perfectly on all the test devices in my office(and on simulator as well). but client said that the app is crashing whenever any image comes, everything else working as expected.
Now the question is if there is any problem than how it is working on my side? **Is there any way(any app or anything) by using them client can send crash report to me so i can check?**

**Note:-** we are testing on the same iOS version(7.x)

**EDIT:-** Some how they get the log and send to me from that i got

```
May 20 22:48:47 iPhone-5S com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.Ba-cha[0xfbd1][287]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.Ba-cha[0xfbd1]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
May 20 22:48:47 iPhone-5S backboardd[31] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.Ba-cha[0xfbd1]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
```

I searched for the same and tried `NSZombieEnabled` but in my device (iPhone 4 and iPhone5) it is working perfectly no log? **And now the question is How can i reproduce the issue on my device?**

Comment: It seems that your app working on iPhone 4 and 5 but crashing on iPhone 5S?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is hit and try solution(at least worked for me):- My app Was worked fine on iPhone4 and 5(32 bit) but crash on iPhone 5s i.e. 64 bit processor. From some research [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452524/memcpy-crash-only-on-iphone-5s) and [Apple official](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) i come to know perhaps there may be some problem in conversion between `NSInteger` to `int`. so i use `NSInteger` every where instead `int`.
Also i'v to remove `armv64` from my project and set `NO` for "Build Active Architecture Only" (debug and release)

That did the trick for me, I didn't really need any 64bit specific functionality on my app so I took it out. I know this is a hack and not a good solution but at least it works.

Comment: You're right that this isn't a good solution. You would do well to figure out what the actual problem was and report back on that instead of working around it.

Answer (score 2):

As Adam suggested, iTunes would work but it may be better to save your client the chore...

You could alternatively send them a new version of the app using something like HockeyApp or TestFlight (free) integrated, allowing you to automatically receive the crash logs as well as the wide range of other useful tools they provide such as easier installation by the client.

Comment: I'v edited my question please have a look and suggest me what to do?

Comment: I believe you should have created a new question rather than updating the existing...now all of our replies make little sense.

Comment: If you can't re-produce it yourself make sure you're testing on the same type of device at least, with the same credentials (if there are any).

Comment: What they've sent is not the crash log but the console log. The crash log (and symbolicated file) could be used to help you find the line in the app where the error's occurring. (TestFlight and HockeyApp can help you do this automatically)

Comment: I'm using same credentials(and of course same data too) on the iPhone4 and 5, but they have iPhone4 and 5s, unfortunately we don't have 5s.. i'll try with TestFlight.

Answer (score 1):

They can load Xcode, and connect the device. Device logs can be viewed in the Organizer window. Crashes are marked as such. The log text can be cut and pasted or the export button can just save the whole thing as text.

Comment: Read this article - http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs - if they can sync the device with iTunes on Windows, they can find the crash logs synced.

Comment: I'v edited my question please have a look and suggest me what to do?

Comment: Sorry but that's not enough information, signal 11 is pretty common! Can't you repeat the crash locally? Get the same device, same data, same steps.

Comment: No i'm not able to reproduce the crash on my device.. this is the first time when i'm not happy when my app running perfectly :P

Answer (score 1):

Crashlytics offers software and service to upload crash logs.

It is possible to build up the information that appears in a crash log, but you will need unix signal handlers,  various exceptions handlers, and a server to upload to.

Comment: Crashlytics is the best one available for getting crash reports.. i am using in multiple projects of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault 11 means memory allocation issue. You possibly have made a coding issue like: using weak/assign, instead strong on NSObject